# Applications icon in the dash keeps disappearing

Tags: unity, unity-dash, applications-lens

Inside the Dash there are some links at the bottom - home, applications, files, music.

The applications icon keeps disappearing, and then reappearing after.  No particular event or key press.

What's wrong?

[image: Error with Application Lens]
[image]

Error confirmed and still occurring intermittently with all updates applied as of 21 Jan '12 Two screenshots above are <1 min apart, nothing else running.

Comment: This question should instead be filed as a bug report, and [as such](http://meta.askubuntu.com/questions/1317/what-to-do-with-questions-that-describe-known-bugs/) is off-topic, thanks! [Instructions here](http://askubuntu.com/questions/5121/how-do-i-report-a-bug).

Answer (score 0):

It's difficult to answer that question based on so little information. But lenses (the different views in the dash) are separate applications that work independently. This means that it is possible for a lens to crash without causing any large issues, and then they would disappear from the dash and be restarted, causing them to come back.

But this is pure speculation. If you are able to provide more details, then it might be possible to expand on the answer, or if it's a problem, then you can file a bug on http://launchpad.net. There are updates for Unity just around the corner, though, so the issue might simply go away as long as you install updates.

Comment: Thanks for the prompt reply.  I am talking about the little icons at the bottom of the screen after I click on dash home.  Home icon is there.  As is, files and folders and music.  But not the applications icon.  I am trying unity-places-application reinstall to see what happens.

Comment: Are you using Unity 2D?